# How to run ndk-gdb after breakpoints attached

Tags: gdb, android-ndk

Ok i have put breakpoints in my native code and now i need to run, problem is i am having problems specifying target i guess. I have a Droid X on which i want to run app and use gdb to debug going thru breakpoints

type

(gdb) run ?????  don't know what to type with run, saw target options but can't understand how to attach to device

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured myself,

Install and run the app on device

Under project go do a ndk-gdb

if everything is ok, and you get a gdb prompt, enter your breakpoints

and type c to continue, i forgot to see ndk gdb doc, it's simple really

Comment: Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.